# Stop an onclick function from another

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a simple onclick function that I want to deactivate from a different function. I have my reason to not use

```
enable = "false"

function x() {
    if (enable === "true") {
        //bla
    }
    else {
        //bla2
}
```

Does anyone know an alternative

Comment: Why do you use `strings` which store Boolean-like values? You can do this `enable = false` and `if (enable)`

Comment: Yes, there are alternatives - for example, detaching \ attaching events. However, this seems to be the easiest approach. One variable, one-line check. What is "my reason"?

Comment: You are probably looking at RemoveEventListener method

Comment: I was trying to do this on a mass scale with Settimeout and using jquery to hide and show elements and there were a lot of bugs. I think I have found a way to do it using setAttribute so i will close the question in a couple hours

Answer (score 0):

```
function(event){
    event.stopPropgation();
}
```

May be this will help you

Comment: You may want to add some details for OP